# About a differential mass element when $\rho = \rho(r)$

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm confused by the fact that, if
$$\rho(r) = m(r)/V(r)$$
then
$$m(r) = \rho(r) V(r)$$
so
$$\frac{dm}{dr} = \frac{d\rho}{dr} V(r) + \frac{dV}{dr} \rho$$
expanding
$$\frac{dm}{dr} = \frac{d\rho}{dr} V(r) + 4\pi r^2 \rho$$
finally

$$\boxed{dm = V(r) d\rho + 4\pi r^2 \rho dr}$$

why is that, e.g., in the context of stars (and *assuming a spherical geometry*), we say that

$$\boxed{\frac{dm}{dr} = 4\pi r^2 \rho}$$

considering:

[image]

$$dm_{\mathrm{box.}} = (dA dr \rho) = (r^2 d\Omega dr) \rho$$
$$dm(r) = \int_{\Omega} dm_{\mathrm{box.}} = 4\pi r^2 dr \rho$$

> **Question**: is it because $\rho \equiv \frac{dm}{dV} \neq \frac{m}{V}$ ?

Comment: 1. Please add more context. For now I am assuming that this is a spherical container of fluid and that we are saying that stars are spheres. 2. Between line four and line five you omit multiplying by rho for the $4 \pi r^2$ term by accident. Is this the problem?

Comment: @novawarrior77 thanks, that was a typo. I added information to clarify the geometry of the issue. 

I think I'm misunderstanding $\rho$ when its written like $\rho = m(r)/V(r)$ as it should be treated as a derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your starting assumption is wrong.  When you write $\rho(r) = m(r)/V(r)$, what are the functions $m(r)$ and $V(r)$ supposed to mean?

The density $\rho(\mathbf r)$ is implicitly defined to be the quantity which you integrate over space to obtain the mass:
$$M = \int \rho(\mathbf r) dV$$

The right way to think about it is to imagine a small volume $\delta V$ centered at the point $\mathbf r$.  If that small volume has mass $\delta m$, then you can calculate the ratio $\frac{\delta m}{\delta V}$, and this is what we call the density $\rho(\mathbf r)$.  In other words,

$$\delta m = \rho(\mathbf r) \delta V$$

In general, there is not a "mass function" which you differentiate with respect to volume (it's not clear what that even means) to obtain the density.  Instead, the density is the thing you integrate to get the mass.